# Multiprocessing doesn't seems to work at all?

Tags: python, threadpool

Why doesn't this works?
Don't get any error.

I though I had used this snippet of code a year ago and though it worked back then but maybe not.. Using python 2.7

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def printer(arg):
    print arg

nThreads = 10

pool = ThreadPool(processes=nThreads)
threads = [pool.apply_async(printer, args=(x)) for x in range(100)]
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `(x)` to `(x,)` or `[x]` solves this.

You can easily see what's wrong by [running](http://ideone.com/INIBum) the following code

```
x = 5 
print type((x))
print type((x,))
print len((x,))
```

As what [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) in `args` is well, [args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) :)

Comment: Really.. Should have read the docs more carefully. Will mark this as correct when I get home.